# Have docker pull images from an insecure registry inside kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I want to configure docker inside kubernetes so that it will use http instead of https to pull container from a specific ip.

I can do that locally by adding this line to the docker json config file :

```
"insecure-registries" : ["mydomain:port"]
```

I want to make it clear that I it's not about using a private registry, it's about using an insecure one.

How can I do that in kubernetes ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add your http registry as a insecure-registry (as you mention in your question) to your docker daemon on each kubernetes node (don't forget the workers).

Comment: Thank you, it works. I really think there should be a kubectl command to do this.